# Preserve YAML files with only comments when formatting using ruamel.yaml?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'd like to preserve comments in YAML files with only comments. With my current setup, ruamel.yaml outputs null upon formatting such a file. Is there a good way to do this? Here is what I have so far:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

def round_trip(sout, sin, idt):
    yaml = YAML()
    assert idt >= 2
    yaml.indent(mapping=idt, sequence=idt, offset=idt-2)
    yaml.preserve_quotes = True

    data = yaml.load(sin)
    if data is not None:
        yaml.dump(data, sout)
    else:
        print("the file is empty") # needs fixing: should dump original file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are not preserved as there is no location on your instance `data`
to put them. In round-trip mode `ruamel.yaml` doesn't create normal Python
dicts/lists from YAML mappings/sequences, but subclasses thereof
(`CommentedMap`/`CommentedSeq`) and attaches comments indexed by the previous
element in those container. At the same time, dunder methods like `__get__()`
allow for (most) normal use of these containers to use and or modify them in
your program and then dump them.

`ruamel.yaml` does subclass strings, integers, floats (and to some extend
booleans) to preserve information on quotes, exponentials, base, any
anchor, etc. that may occur in your YAML. But if comments would be
attached to a scalar, instead of the container of which it is a value or
element, would result in loss of that comment on assignment of a new value. That
is if you have YAML:

```
a: 18  # soon to be 55
b: 42
```

load that into `data` and do `data['a'] = 55` your comment would be lost. It am
not sure if this behaviour can be improved upon, by making the container
smarter, that is worth investigating, but only if such a scalar is part of mapping/sequence.

Apart from that `None` cannot be subclassed, so there is no place to attach
comments. Booleans cannot be subclassed either, but to preserve anchors `ruamel.yaml`
constructs booleans as a subclass of `int`, which allows for normal usage e.g. in
`if` statements testing for the truth value. A typical usage for `None`
however is testing for identity (using `... is None``) and AFAIK there is no way to fake that.

So there is no way for `.load()` to give you something back that has the comment
information. But you do yave the `YAML()` instance and IMO it is best to
subclass that to preserve the comment information. It currently stores some
information about the last loaded document, e.g. the documents YAML version
directive if provided (`%YAML 1.1`)

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
# this document is, by default,
# round-tripped to null
"""

class YAML(ruamel.yaml.YAML):
    def load(self, stream):
        if not hasattr(stream, 'read') and hasattr(stream, 'open'):
            # pathlib.Path() instance
            data = super().load(stream)
            if data is None:
                buf = stream.read_text()
        elif isinstance(stream, str):
            data = super().load(stream)
            buf = stream
        else:  # buffer stream data
             buf = stream.read()
             data = super().load(buf)
        if data is None and buf.strip():
             self._empty_commented_doc = buf
        return data

    def dump(self, data, stream=None, transform=None):
        # dump to stream or Path
        if not hasattr(self, '_empty_commented_doc'):  # the simple case
            return super().dump(data, stream=stream, transform=transform)
        # doesn't handle transform
        if not hasattr(stream, 'read') and hasattr(stream, 'open'):
            with stream.open('w') as fp:
                fp.write(self._empty_commented_doc)
                super().dump(data, stream)
        else:
            stream.write(self._empty_commented_doc)
            if data is not None:
                super().dump(data, stream)


yaml = YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
# yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
data = True
print('----------------')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
# this document is, by default,
# round-tripped to null
----------------
# this document is, by default,
# round-tripped to null
true
...
```

---

<sup>The above could be extended to handle root level scalar documents as well, and
I'm considering adding a more complete implementation to ruamel.yaml.</sup>